# Prove the inequality (law of total variance)

Tags: probability, statistics

Anyone can guide me on this question?

$$E[\operatorname{Var}(Y\mid X)]\leq \operatorname{Var}(Y)$$

Thank you, appreciate your help!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance#Proof Then note that both terms are nonnegative.

Comment: This is the "unexplained" component of the variance of $Y$, i.e. the part not explained by the variability of $X$: $$ \underbrace{\operatorname{E}(\operatorname{var}(Y\mid X))}_\text{unexplained} + \underbrace{\operatorname{var}(\operatorname{E}(Y\mid X))}_\text{explained} = \operatorname{var}(Y) $$ ${}\qquad{}$